# How to print out a string that is pointed to by a char pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I have this program which intends to test two things:

1. Once assigned, a string cannot be assigned to another string.
2. Two char pointers however can point to the same string.

// Program-

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char str[]="hello";
    char str2[10];
    int i=0;
    char *s="Good";
    char *p;

    //error
    //str=str2;
    printf("String str2: %s\n", str);
    //no error
    p=s;
    //printf("String pointed to by p: %s\n", *p );
    while(*s!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
        s++;
        i++;

    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting a garbage value when I print out the contents "Good". Same for any other word. Is something going wrong in the while loop?

Comment: `s++; i++;` Move is duplicated. remove `i++;`

Comment: why do you need `char *p`?

Comment: Unrelated, But you have some unused variables there

Answer (score 2):

You increment both the array index and the pointer `s`: During the first iteration, `i == 0` and `s` points to `G` in the string `Good`. At the second iteration, `s` points to the first `o` and `i == 1`, so `s[i]` is the second `o`, which is probably not what you want.

If you comment out the `i++`, everything will work as intended: http://ideone.com/7zUOfM

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Although the code works on removing the i++, I'm not sure I fully understand. Like you said, in the first iteration, i is zero, and s points to the character "G". In the second iteration, i is 1, so s[1] should point to the character "O"- meaning the first O, because it's the second element in the string. So, why does it point to the third element, ie: the second "O"? It looks different from pointer arithmetic using integers/floating points!

Comment: Because by incrementing `s` through `s++`, you move the pointer `s` by one character to the right. In fact, for any pointer, `*(s + i)` and `s[i]` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

In this loop

```
while(*s!='\0')
{
    printf("%c", s[i]);
    s++;
    i++;

}
```

you are incrementing simultaneously index `i`

```
    i++;
```

and the pointer to the string literal

```
    s++;
```

So this results in some garbage because `s[i]` for some `i` and `s` after their incrementing will access memory beyond the string literal.

You should only either increase index i or corresponding pointer. For example you could write simply

```
while ( *p ) printf( "%c", *p++ );
```

Comment: Thank You! Your last line of code was very simple to understand!

Comment: @Manish I though that the simpler code the easy to understand it.:)